# can't resolve symbole 'default' ( intellij 2017 )

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am using intellij 2017

For consistency reasons, I would like to use named imports when importing default export from certain module

```
import { default as React } from 'react'
```

I got the following analyze error:

[image: can't resolve symbol 'default']

Although I think it is irrelevant, just as little detail, I am using webpack + babel-loader with presets [ 'react', 'es2015', 'stage-0' ]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, please follow [WEB-28276](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28276) for updates